# Why is there no Object.setPrototypeOf(...) in ECMAScript standard?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, prototype

Apparently using `__proto__` property is still the main way of manipulating prototype chains, even though this is not standards compliant and IE does not support it. Though you can also construct inheritance through the use of `new` constructor this seems like an unnecessary complication compared to `__proto__` property or standards compliant `Object.getPrototypeOf` function.

**Edit:**

As stated in the answers, this method does exist now (ES6 standard). Be aware of the performance warning, though: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf

Comment: good news. it seems Object.setPrototypeOf() got into ES6 http://webreflection.blogspot.pt/2013/05/objectsetprototypeofo-proto-is-in-es6.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is part of the ES6 harmony draft:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf

I am using it now in the latest release of Chrome.

```
var proto = {
    foo: 'bar'
};

var object = {};

Object.setPrototypeOf(object, proto);

console.assert(object.foo == 'bar');
```

Answer (score 2):

[Brendan Eich](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brendan_Eich) says this [here](http://brendaneich.com/2011/01/harmony-of-my-dreams/#div-comment-6121):

> Object.setPrototypeOf is not going to happen. Writable __proto__ is a
>   giant pain to implement (must serialize to cycle-check) and it creates
>   all sorts of type-confusion hazards. You may think you want it as a
>   low-level sharp instrument. JS is not that language. Higher-level
>   forms for classes and mixins seem much better and do not involve such
>   sharp edges.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though i have to admit i don't fully understand it. Your idea is to add non-prototype based inheritance in Javascript? In my mind Object.setPrototypeOf would simply create prototype object reference, so i don't understand how this would require serialization.

Comment: Seems like he was wrong :)

Just got in in Chrome: https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/detail?r=18685

and, it's experimental in Firefox already:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf

Comment: @Esailija what's your opinion on this in 2017? You seem to get "serious" when it's performance and optimization (in libs you write/contribute) so I'd like to know what you think.

Comment: The proliferation of powerful languages mean that engineers are now more powerful. Mere "pain to implement" is never going to a good excuse, if not now, then in the future.